# SvelteKit: Run function at route change (for access token, without doing it at a layout file)

Tags: routes, access-token, svelte, sveltekit

I just started with SvelteKit and I have a question regarding **functions, that should run on every route change**. I did not find much, helpful information about it.

Just to run it at the **layout files (which I do not prefer**, because I might probably use multiple layout files and prefer one global place.)

**In Vue.js**, I do something like that, to check at every route change, if there is an access token (at the end of the router file):

```
// src/router/index.ts
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  AUTHENTICATION.default.fetchAccessToken();
  if (to.options.protected && !AUTHENTICATION.default.tokenData) {
    next("/");
  } else next();
});
```

**How would I achive that in SvelteKit?**

Would that work with **svelte-routing in SvelteKit?**
... and is that **in general a good idea, to check an access token**?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use the `navigating` store.

`navigating` is a readable store. When navigating starts, its value is `{ from, to, type }`, where `from` and `to` both mirror the `page` store value. When navigating finishes, its value reverts to `null`.

```js
import { navigating } from '$app/stores';
```

in the `<script>` tag, should `$:` marks a statement as reactive.
Therefore it will be executed every time when navigating happened.

```js
$: if($navigating) myFunction();
```

Of course you can use it in the HTML template.

```js
{#if $navigating}
    <LoadingIndicator />
{/if}
```

More info about navigation:
[https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#modules-$app-stores](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-stores-navigating)

Comment: Hi there. Thanks, that looks quite good and is very helpful. Do you have an idea, where to place that, to have it at a single point and I do not need to import it in every layout-file or so?

Comment: I think a root __layout file is the best place for this.
That's why I should move the whole app into an /app folder.

Comment: In 2022.09.01 - The default(just like root) layout `src/routes/+layout.svelte`  is the best place for this. [Read more.](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#layout)